# 'bit_ceil' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, binary, bit, bitmask

I am trying to use `bit_ceil()`, I included the `<bit>` header, and used the `std` namespace (I know that it is not a good practice, but I did it here for the sake of the question).

But when I try to use the function it just raises an error `'bit_ceil' was not declared in this scope`.

### The full code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <bit>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int x = 1;
    x = bit_ceil(x);

}
```

Weird, anyone got an idea?

The questions regarding this function are scarce around the internet.

Comment: Is this the first/top error?

Comment: Are you using C++20?

Comment: @273K the is the first and only error in the terminal, so yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is something introduced in C++20 so you need to add in your command line (if using GCC) `-std=c++20`

https://godbolt.org/z/chqaYG1bf

Comment: @273 the file is there if your compiler supports C++20 .